# I don't understand this sentence using as ... will fit?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I just read a sentence:

> For sessions the preview shows the active panes in as many windows will fit; for windows as many panes as will fit; and for panes only the selected pane.

So it seems that the preview would show all windows when it's possible. But I don't know how the subsequent "; for windows ...; and for panes" constraints means.

Comment: It tells you what happens under three different circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split that up, using the semicolons as cues, into:

> For sessions the preview shows the active panes in as many windows will fit

> For windows the preview shows the active panes in as many panes will fit

> For panes the preview shows only the selected pane